# What is the most efficient way to get the number of digits before and after a decimal point of a floating point number in Java?

Tags: java

Let's assume I have the number  76.9

If the number is a string I can use somehow the substring method and count the number of digits before and after.

If the number is a Double or Float, I can use some kind of arithmetic to count the number of digits before and after.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't catch. Just modified my question.

Comment: Floats can be imprecise. Therefore, the number of digits can easily change because of precision problems. Therefore, it doesn't make much sense to reason about their number. Why do you care about it?

Comment: Floating point variables don't have decimal digits: they have binary digits; and the two are incommensurable.

Comment: The `double` expressed as `76.9` isn't mathematically equal to 76.9.  You'll need to figure out whether you mean the number of decimal places in its exact mathematical representation, or the number of decimal places you'd get when Java prints it.  If you mean the latter (and I think you do), then you're pretty much stuck with converting it to a `String` and counting.